# Detecting lines (vertical and horizontal) that are not straight and align image by it?

Tags: python, opencv, alignment, surf, hough-transform

**Hey,**

**Is it possible to automatic align an image based on lines in the images that are not straight using Python?
for example, if I have this image:**

[image]

**I want to automatically find lines that are not straight, as shown:**
[image]
[image]
[image]

**After finding this lines I want to align the image based on it, so the image will be something like that (this image was aligned in this method manually with Lightroom):**
[image]

Do you guys have any lead on how to do something like that, maybe an algorithm that someone wrote that can do something similar? 
Firstly I tried using ORB and ECC methods to align the image but it didn't give me a precise result that I could work with,
So I thought of using smarter methods and really find the lines but when I tried to find lines, with [hough line transform](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html) the result was a spread of lines all over the place (because of the small lines between the bricks).

I searched online and found a [lecture](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~urtasun/courses/CV/lecture06.pdf) from Toronto university that talks about this, but I couldn't figure out how to implement those methods in order to create such an algorithm, as mentioned above, finding the lines with Python was pretty complex.

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track with the Hough transform.  Yes, there are a *lot* of lines.
You failed to describe what differentiates the lines you want from the ones you don't (among various unspecified details), but let me try to extract a few ideas for you:

- slope "near" vertical or horizontal.
- longest line(s) in each direction.

Use Hough to find all the lines it can.  Run another pass to concatenate a series of line segments (fit the same linear equation?) into longer lines.  For instance, you should be able to identify the left edge of the shower curtain even though it passes behind the sink.

Now, you want at least the longest line in each direction.  Also consider the "frame" case: if that line is well off-center (say, in the outer 25% of the photo), then also look for a sufficiently long line in the same direction, but on the opposite side.

Each of these processes is easily quantified and checked with basic linear algebra.  You can simplify the process by sorting the line segments appropriately to enhance each operation.

Is that enough outline and hints to get you moving?

Comment: Thank you for replying!
What you wrote helped me a lot to understand the technocritical part, but I can't manage to find the correct lines, whenever I try to find the lines using Hough transform it gives me the lines between the bricks, so practically I can't manage to get the "first" stage done.
I used OpenCV, is there any better way that you could recommend me on?

Comment: The transform should have given you the longer lines, as well.  If not, then there's a problem with the algorithm.  You'd have to look up a better Hough package.